# My question is shown modified by someone else but no details shown in revision

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I did ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33127507/3975838) question in stackoverflow which shows modified by someone else like the screenshot below

[image]

But when i go to revisions i see no such modification or edit there by that user.

Answer (score 6):

That user posted an answer to your question, but changed their mind and deleted it shortly after.

Comment: Thank you. But cant this thing be represented in a better way? It creates a bit confusion.

Comment: Not sure. Perhaps it could be represented differently for users with < 10k rep who can't see deleted answers (as this information can be useful to those who can see them). I don't know if there's already a feature request for that.